# Ionic radii of transition metal ions in the presence of weak field and strong field ligands

Tags: transition-metals, atomic-radius, crystal-field-theory

[image: The variation of Ionic radius among 3rd-period Transition metals]

‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
In the graph given in this image,‎ I was told by my teacher‎ that whenever we start filling the eg orbitals there is an increase in the radius because these orbitals face the ligand directly and hence the repulsion causes the radius to increase.‎
However, my reasoning says that due to ligand repulsion to electron cloud of that eg orbital, the size should rather decrease. I am confused‎
Is what Sir said true? help me in comprehending this.‎

Comment: Would this be for octahedral coordination of all the ions shown? We need to compare apples and apples when it comes to ionic radii, and crystal field or ligand field splitting changes with different coordination geometries.

Comment: Yes, it is for the octahedral geometry of the ligand around the metal ion.